# How to filter input to a batch file?

Tags: variables, batch-file, input, filter

I am pretty new at this (I literally only started learning about batch scripts yesterday) and I got an idea to make my job easier. Ha. I work at my university and students got IDs; we've got magnet stripe readers plugged into our working stations, so I'm trying to write a script that takes in the input from the card. However, the card has a bunch of random character that I don't need, say ~#$@%#@!=#20052, for example. I was wondering if there's a way to filter the input into a variable, like in C, that would only take the student ID. I'm not asking for anybody to write the code, but just the broad idea of how to filter input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hard to say, if we don't know how the complete string looks like and what part of it you need. Does it start/end at specific positions, does it start/end with or after/before a specific character, are all the strings of the same length and format ...

Comment: @Stephan I see both a `%` and a `!` in the unwanted characters, oh god...

Comment: It's constant, say %00000; 1111111=00234$!
I basically would only like to get the 1111111 value, so it always begins with a value, % or ; evreytime

Comment: Do all codes have **only one** space before them and a `=` sign after them?

Comment: Yes, and my bad, there's no space, here's an example: '%abc123;001534523=00331x' and i would like to get only the 001534523

Comment: `echo %x:~8,9%` for your last example

Comment: you said "it's constant" - but by now we have three different formats and lengths. Don't make a riddle of it, please.

Comment: Well I was just asking how to get rid of certain characters, so I'd do it myself and learn, my apologies, but I still appreciate the help, thank you very much. To be fair I won't try this until Monday at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=%abc123;001534523=00331x"
call set "string=!string:%%=!"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=;=" %%i in ("%string%") do set "code=%%i"
echo(%code%
pause
```

**NOTE**

This does require that there is only one `;` before the code, and no `=` before it, but one directly after. Basically it works for any string of the format `x;code=x`

It also removes all `%` signs.

To use this easily you can do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=%~1"
call set "string=!string:%%=!"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=;=" %%i in ("%string%") do set "code=%%i"
echo(%code%
pause
```

And than call you batch-file like this: `yourBatFile.bat "%abc123;001534523=00331x"`

Comment: Why are you eliminating the `%` from the string? That should not be necessary.

Comment: This worked like wonder. Thank you very much. Off to experiment!

Comment: @ricknaght If my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.

Comment: My bad, thought that was done by upvoting but it wouldn't let me. I've checked it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are unix tools that have been converted to work in command mode.  you could use gawk which is a very powerfull string manupulation tool.

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/